# best (or at least good) guide to Java annotations

Tags: java, annotations

There must be a good book/PDF/HTML file that describes the essentials & good practices of annotations in Java. I sort of know what they are from other good Java books, but I'm looking for something that would teach me most of what I would need to know to make good use of them. (preferably in PDF/HTML so I can print it out & read at my leisure, book ok also but those go out of date so fast...)

Any recommendations?

edit: I found the Sun guides, as well as tutorials like these from [O'Reilly](http://www.onjava.com/lpt/a/4768) and [DevX](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/27235/1954?pf=true), and the section of [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058) that covers them... OK, so I know what they are and what tools to read them, but that doesn't tell me much about how they are put to use in practice. (other than a little bit in Effective Java and the O'Reilly article above that suggest their use in automated testing frameworks)

Answer (score 7):

- Some opinions on annotations:
  http://web.archive.org/web/20120115164115/http://faler.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/when-to-use-and-not-to-use-java-annotations
- This guy is very much against them:
  https://web.archive.org/web/20060702222249/http://www.softwarereality.com/programming/annotations.jsp
- Best Practices: http://willcode4beer.com/opinion.jsp?set=annotations_gotchas_best_practices

Hope this helps. Let us know what you find.